# Fastlane failing at step gym, getting Exit Status: 65, CodeSign build commands failing

Tags: fastlane

Sorry if this is a dumb question this is my first go around with Fastlane and I’m having some issues.

I’m running the command:

```
fastlane ios beta
```

and the process is failing in gym, the error is the following:

```
The following build commands failed:
CodeSign /Users/cm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OnDeck-ftohruvlpgqajhhbppffshjfjvwm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/OnDeck/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FLKAutoLayout.framework
CodeSign /Users/cm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OnDeck-ftohruvlpgqajhhbppffshjfjvwm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/OnDeck/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/CocoaAsyncSocket.framework
CodeSign /Users/cm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OnDeck-ftohruvlpgqajhhbppffshjfjvwm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/OnDeck/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Cosmos.framework
CodeSign /Users/cm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OnDeck-ftohruvlpgqajhhbppffshjfjvwm/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/OnDeck/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/EZLoadingActivity.framework
(4 failures)
[15:52:12]: Exit status: 65
[15:52:12]: Variable Dump:
[15:52:12]: {:DEFAULT_PLATFORM=>:ios, :PLATFORM_NAME=>:ios, :LANE_NAME=>"ios beta"}
[15:52:12]: Error building the application - see the log above

+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|                     fastlane summary                     |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                              | Time (in s) |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | Verifying required fastlane version | 0           |
| 2    | default_platform                    | 0           |
| 3    | cocoapods                           | 9           |
| 4    | gym                                 | 22          |
+------+-------------------------------------+-------------+

[15:52:12]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Error building the application - see the log above
```

I’m kinda at a loss here when i comes to debugging this issue and my research has yielded little results. I have run Xcode-select —install so I’m on version 7.1.1(the latest at this point)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug this issue ?

Thx!

Update:
GitHub issue and further discussion on this at https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/4197

Comment: Unfortunately, Exit status: 65 is a really common error state, so it's hard to know what's happening. We've tried to capture the best practices for success with fastlane and code signing over here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/xcode-project/

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here just in case it can help someone else:

I was getting the same error (**CodeSign 65**) on my Jenkins server. To fix it I used the following flag in `gym`:

```
keychain_password: "my_Mac_Password"
```

Where **my_Mac_Password** is your MacOS password for the user who is running Jenkins.

It only needs to work once, after which you can remove this flag from fastlane.

**Note** A better solution, if you are using Jenkins, would be to add the [keychain_password](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/setup_jenkins/) environment variable to your Jenkins configuration.